# Creating a delimited text using regex

Tags: regex, excel, ms-word

I have a glossary where the entries are given in bold text, and the explanatory text is regular font. What I'd like to do is to add a comma (asterisk or any other punctuation sign) after every string of bolded text, which would then enable me to turn the glossary into a comma delimited text in Excel. Is there a way to do this using regular expressions in Word's find and replace dialog box, so I can get a comma at the end of the word or phrase which is an entry in the glossary. Here's one entry from the glossary as an example:

**To abolish at entry into force**  ....content of the entry in regular font..

The entry is the bolded phrase, and the explanation associated with it is given in regular text.

After trying the expression **<[A-Za-z\,.-)(/\?! ]{1,}>** Jerry suggested in the Find box and **^&,** in the Replace box in MS Word, I get the desired result for the phrases in bold which are followed by a paragraph break, such as titles and headings:

---

http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/6338/frontpagep.jpg

---

but no changes happen on the glossary entries, because they are followed by the content of the entry, with no paragraph break after them. Here's a sample from the glossary, showing the characteristic layout of the glossary entries:

---

http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/6558/samplefromtheglossary.jpg

---

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards, set format font to bold. For search, enter `<*>`. For replace, enter `^&,`. [Picture is worth a thousand scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCJyt.png)

Comment: It works George, but the problem is that I get a comma after each word, and I need it to place a comma after a string of words in bold, because some entries are phrases. For example in the phrase: "documents, that, accompany, the, request", I need a comma only after the last word "request" to be able to delimit it from the content of this entry in Excel

Comment: This is not possible with straight MS Word. You will have to find another tool or approach. If you save the file as a Web Page (*.htm,*.html), you can do a find on `</b>` and replace on `</b>,`. Hopefully you don't lose too much formatting between the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple searching around shows the following documents that apply to older versions of Word- up to 2002 at least.

[office support document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087304)

Note that Word's implementation of Regex is not very conformant to other people's implementations.

I didn't see a doc for a more recent version of Word. The Search and Replace in Visual Studio (I think this works in the free version too), or in an IDE like Eclipse, does support Regex, so you have lots of non-Word options that might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one:

`<[A-Za-z\,\.\-\)\(\/\?\! ]{1,}>`

Instead of the find of `<*>` George suggested previously?

**Following new edit of OP:**

You could try putting this in a macro:

```
Sub CommaAdder()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<[A-Za-z]@>"
        .Replacement.Text = "^&,"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ",([\)])"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1,"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ",([\-\?\/\!\.\, ])"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "([A-Za-z]@ )"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1,"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "( \,)([A-Za-z]@)"
        .Replacement.Text = ", \2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\,\("
        .Replacement.Text = "("
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\, "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " \,"
        .Replacement.Text = ", "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

I don't know how to write macros, but I recorded one replace to build this up and if you understand that a bit, there are 3 replaces going on one after the other. The first looks for all bold words and puts a comma in between them, even if there are `)` or `.`, etc. The second looks specifically for the instances I just mentioned to remove that comma, and the ones where we have a comma followed by a bold white space `,`, except the `,)` part, which is addressed in the last replace, where it replaces that with `),` instead.

The issue is that if you have something like:

> **This is bold** but not this

The white space between `bold` and `but` also having the `bold` format, it will be removed at the second replace. If there was one way to find text with part bold and part not bold, there wouldn't be any issue. I'm trying to look for a solution to that, but let me know if there are any issues with this code. If there is no white space formatted as bold like that, there won't be any issue!

**reEDIT:** This works for bold spaces too now! Though it's not too neat...

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you, I've just tried your suggestion, and I got a comma before hyphens within phrases in bold like:
**back,-up measure** , and I got commas in the end of bold phrases when they end with something added in brackets, and the comma is placed before the right bracket, for example: **contracting parties hereby agree (to,) . But I don't get comma anywhere where no punctuation is included in the bolded phrase such as in:  **under treatment no less favourable than that accorded to**

Comment: @TotoKalvera You have hyphens as well? I guess that's a limitation of the current find. Try adding `\-` like this: `<[A-Za-z\- ]{1,}>`. I'll add that to my answer above shortly. EDIT: Oh, `<[A-Za-z -]{1,}>` works as well!

Comment: @TotoKalvera Could you include the specific sentences in your original question? It gets a little hard to follow in the comments ^^;

Comment: @TotoKalvera Okay, I was expecting some kind of list of different sentence structures you have... If I sum up what you require: you need a comma after all bold phrases (which may include hyphen, brackets) but not where the bold phrase end with any punctuation mark (".", ",", "?","!")?

Comment: I apologize for the unclear question Jerry. I'd be more than happy if I can have comma added at the end of bolded entries that don't contain any punctuation, hyphens or brackets, like the one in my example. Some entries contain hyphens like **back-up measures** and some have brackets at the end like: **charges having an equivalent effect (to)**. The entries that contain brackets or hyphens are rare and I'd manually remove punctuation from them, it's not a problem, as long as I can have a comma at the end of the other entries, which do not contain any punctuation, only text.

Comment: @TotoKalvera Okay, let's try again: `<[A-Za-z\,\.\-\)\?\! ]{1,}>` It's becoming a little ugly though, haha ^^;

Comment: Again the same, it works like this for the entries that are followed by brackets, slashes or hyphens: **supporting document,(s)** or **obligations arising from,/out** which means that it inserts comma before the punctuation sign contained in the entry. No changes happen on normal entries like: **Amendments to the Protocol**.

Comment: I'm adding them to the 'list of things to include as phrase. `<[A-Za-z\,\.\-\)\(\/\?\! ]{1,}>`. See that I added `\(` and `\/`? Maybe you could add some characters as and when you see fit =)

Comment: Thank you again Jerry.This is very interesting, the last expression you gave works like a charm if the bolded phrase is followed by a paragraph break, so I got exactly what I asked for in the document titles, but not in the glossary entries where I actually need it, because they are not separated from the content by a paragraph mark. Is it too big a problem to solve? Even if I managed to insert paragraph breaks after each entry manually, that wouldn't be an option because then I couldn't delimit entries in Excel.I don't know the syntax of regex so I can't tweak it on my own right now.

Comment: Could you include a couple of lines from your glossary in your original post? Maybe you could run two find and replace, one specific tot he document, and one specific for the glossary, depending on how they are structured. And I know that glossary can be differently structured, so what's why I'm asking for a sample. Because otherwise, I don't have any idea what characters to add or remove in the expression :(

Comment: I've added samples from the glossary to my original post Jerry, showing what happens when I apply your expression in the Find/Replace box in MS Word.

Comment: @TotoKalvera I've got something, but I wanted to know first if you have any 'bold' spaces in your document after a bold phrase but before a non-bold phrase?E.g. " **Text** [ ]moretext " and the white space in the square bracket (the square bracket is only to show and doesn't exist in the actual text) is bold.

Comment: Your macro works like a charm with the document I have! Here's how it looks in Word (paragraph marks, spaces and breaks shown) http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9494/wordsample.jpg which allowed me to make a neatly delimited Excel glossary http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/9601/sampleu.jpg I've tried to do this with another dictionary I have, but here's the case as you said, the space which follows bolded phrases is also in bold,  http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/5908/snapshotehu.jpg , and it doesn't work- only entries that end with punctuation sign or paragraph break get comma at the end.

Comment: Which means that the second replace doesn't remove bold spaces between bolded and unbolded text. The macro works perfectly in the glossary where the spaces following bold phrases are in regular font, but not in the dictionary where they are bolded.

Comment: @TotoKalvera I added some more stuff and it seems to work for me. Would you maybe try the new one?

Comment: Works almost perfectly Jerry! It does work with bold spaces too. It doesn't add comma to bolded phrases only if they end in a punctuation mark like brackets, slashes or so as: **caliph (calif)** or when the phrase is followed by two or more spaces. Trying to create a delimited dictionary I've come up another, related problem to this, with separating subentries in bold from the main entry to the dictionary. I'll ask a separate question about it, hope I catch you around to help me with that one too:)

Comment: It's good if they don't add a punctuation mark after the slash and bracket, right? Or is it wrong and I thought otherwise? I'm not sure... Oops!

Comment: No Jerry, by punctuation marks I meant slashes, brackets and so. Rare entries, such as **caliph** contain alternative spellings in brackets, some other contain similar things, which means that the ending of the bolded phrase is a bracket or a slash. In such cases your macro doesn't add a comma at the end. It doesn't work if the bolded phrase is followed by more than one space either. Otherwise, it does the thing I asked for, and I'm more than happy with it, thank you very much :)

Comment: Oh, okay then. Maybe you could alter the first replace a bit and replace `[A-Za-z]` by `*`, which George initially pointed out but will work better with the other replaces. If it works, wonderful! :D. Also, do you need the double spaces? Doing a "find 2 spaces replace by 1 space" could do the trick.

Comment: Yes Jerry, works like a charm, thank you:) I don't need double space after the entries, I'll replace them with a single space.